# Getting the bodycam video from NYPD for a traffic violation

Tags: new-york-city, criminal-procedure

I got a bike ticket for going through a red light.
I don’t think I did.

The officer confirmed that he was wearing his body cam and that it was on.

How do I go about getting the bodycam video? I have been trying to obtain it through foil requests but they are unsuccessful: NYPD claims giving me the bodycam would interfere with my case.

Comment: Where did the alleged violation occur?

Comment: There are records access appeals officers who handle appeals of denied FOIL requests. They are required to give particularized and specific justification for nondisclosure. Can you include the specific reason for the FOIL denial?

Answer (score 2):

The cops don't necessarily have to give you the video footage, the prosecuting attorney does.  You are entitled to discovery before a trial of any exonerating evidence. The district attorney must furnish all evidence to you if it exists before trial and the cops may not supress it. You need to make a demand for discovery but the particulars of this process vary.

Answer (score 1):

IANAL, but I have some experience.  ***You are screwed.***  Even if you are acquitted of the charges, you will have spent so much on lawyers, court, and other things that you will effectively have been punished.

1. You need to decide whether you want to fight this or not.  If you choose not to fight this, you will limit your losses.
2. If you fight this, you need to hire a lawyer.  Advice from stackoverflow will not cut it.  The NYPD will use every trick in the book to keep you from apart from any exonerating evidence.
3. You are going to have to go court a lot.  The NYPD will try to wear you out with court appearances.
4. For the future, you should invest in a bike cam.  Just assume the cops won't give you their video and make your own.

Comment: As I am a programmer, I am not interested in stackoverflow telling me whether it should be done - only how it can be done. 

I am only asking - how do I get the bodycam from the city. There must be a procedure to do so. I want only to know this.

Comment: @iamacomputer if the NYPD wanted you to get the footage it would be easy.  Clearly they do not want you to get the footage.  It is an adversarial process and they have more experience at thwarting requests than you have at making them.  You need to hire someone who has succeeded in getting the NYPD to do what it does not want to do.

Comment: @iamacomputer `There must be a procedure to do so. I want only to know this.` I think the procedure is that you get a judge to order the NYPD to give you the footage.

Comment: This is ridiculous.  If there is a way to do it- then there is a way to do it.    Following a set of steps submitting paper work to where-ever should not be "mysterious" or "secret."

Comment: I think the suggestion that you get a lawyer is the procedure.  I doubt there's a form 9173c you fill out and *bam* you get the footage.  You'll most likely have to file some kind of legal brief or sue the police department to get the footage.  The judge probably wouldn't grant it for a simple traffic citation.

Comment: Can you use discovery in traffic court? Thats the normal method for getting evidence like this.

Comment: Can you describe the experience on which this answer is based?  My experience is that the NYPD officer didn't take notes and the ticket was dismissed after he testified that he didn't remember the incident.

Comment: @iamacomputer It is ridiculous.  Not only is there a "secret" procedure but you have to have a license to invoke the "secret" procedure . I am not describing what I think the procedure should be.  I am describing what I think the procedure is.  I would be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: @phoog I got a bogus ticket in another jurisdiction.  My amateur efforts at discovery achieved nothing.  I think the procedure was that the case was first heard in "district court" which has a 99.9% conviction rate.  If I filed within the prescribed deadline I could have the trial "de novo" in circuit court.  I believe discovery is not available in district court but is available in circuit court.  I think I would have failed without a lawyer and it did not make sense to spend thousands to escape a $100 fine.

Comment: @phoog if OP goes to the equivalent of district court he should definitely when given a chance determine if the citing officer took notes and/or remembers the incident.  If not, then it is likely the ticket will be dismissed and OP will not need the video.

Comment: @iamacomputer check this out https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/free-books/beat-ticket-book/chapter9-3.html (1) you may/may not have a right to discovery at traffic court (i don't know); (2) the NYPD will probably ignore your request anyway; (3) if you do not do everything proper the judge will blame you for failing to dot an "i" or cross a "t" and deny you discovery.  The NYPD has more experience thwarting discovery requests than you have making them.  Do you really think the agency that gave you a bogus ticket is going to be reasonable?

Comment: @iamacomputer Consider https://www.arlnow.com/2019/06/05/inside-the-fight-over-access-to-criminal-case-documents-in-arlington/.  It is obvious that the prosecutor is using concerns about "witness intimidation" to limit discovery.  But under that regime you would have to hire a lawyer to go to the prosecutor's office to watch the video and write a summary using pen and paper.  Who knows what dirty hardball tactics the NYPD will use to keep the video from you? A lawyer with experience in NYPD traffic cases.